# Kubernetes CronJob public IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cron-task, kubernetes-security

I have simple Kubernetes CronJob connecting to a remote database.
The remote database uses an IP filter, so each database connection should come from the same IP.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Hint: I am using AKS (Azure). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Cheers,
Tibor

Comment: Is the remote database running on Azure? Or local?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress#egress-traffic-overview), the outgoing ip address is based on the load balancer IP deployed in the cluster. Check the docs for more details!